# How to detect when MPRIS player is added or removed on D-Bus?

Tags: dbus, freedesktop.org

So far the only way I found is to call [ListNames](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#bus-messages-list-names) method on `org.freedesktop.DBus` periodically, and check if any `org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.*` is added or removed.

But isn't there a better way? For example, is there a D-Bus signal notifying about changes in the list of bus names, to avoid calling `ListNames` periodically?

Comment: The `InterfacesAdded` signal is emitted when either a new object is added or when an existing object gains one or more interfaces

Comment: Thanks @ukBaz, this is from `org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager` interface, as I understand. But I'm confused which bus/object that implements this interface I should look for... `org.freedesktop.DBus` bus objects don't seem to implement it.

Comment: Ah, it seems it can be done with `org.freedesktop.DBus.NameOwnerChanged` signal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signal is [NameOwnerChanged](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#bus-messages-name-owner-changed) on the `org.freedesktop.DBus` bus. It has 3 arguments: name, old owner, and new owner.

If there is no old owner (empty string), only a new one, then the name was added. And vice-versa, if there is no new owner, then the name was removed.

To filter players-only bus names the name can be checked to start with `org.mpris.MediaPlayer2`.